# LTSpice error: Time step too small

Tags: ltspice, simulation, texas-instruments, error

[image]
I am trying to simulate the Buck Converter LM22676 from TI for a 5V output. But LTSpice shows an error saying that the time step is too small when I try to run a transient analysis. Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You might try some initial conditions or putting a resistance in series with V1.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried replicating the schematic from the datasheet at page 14, you didn't do a good job: you missed the output feedback network. And you chose a `1k` value for the output load, which is questionable for an output that's meant to deliver `3.3 V @ 3 A`; I've made it `1` Ω. Not lastly, `C1` and `C2` are useless without some series resistance between the supply and them.

That said, the model works, though, for some reason, the output doesn't stabilize at `3.3 V`. The soft-start is meant to bring up the output after some 500 µs; the duration is right, the value is not. To be sure we're talking about the same thing, [this is the model I used](https://www.ti.com/lit/zip/snvm819). The symbol is auto-generated so you won't have problems replicating my schematic.

Still, I've made the following modifications (seen in the picture, below), though you may get lucky and not need any:

- added `Rser=1m` to the bootstrap capacitor
- added `Rser=50m` to the output filter capacitor
- added `Rser=10m Cpar=1m` to the input voltage source
- added `uic` to the simulation card since LTspice has trouble finding an operating point; just start from zero and it will be fine.

[image: works]